# Behaviors in Polymer: where is the part of code that applies listeners and properties?

Tags: polymer

Polymer allows you to define [behaviors](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html). While anything that is not "special" is mixed in (and that's OK), special things (like lifecycle functions, as well as properties and listeners) are not.
Specifically, these are not mixed in:

```
Polymer.Base._behaviorProperties = {
  hostAttributes: true,
  beforeRegister: true,
  registered: true,
  properties: true,
  observers: true,
  listeners: true,
  created: true,
  attached: true,
  detached: true,
  attributeChanged: true,
  ready: true
}
```

What I cannot find anywhere, is this: where in Polymer's code are the `listeners` **in the element's behaviours** added? What about `properties`?

I am sure the key is here:

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/273ab0fbe641209fa3fc3ce8368bb78f83db9b10/polymer.html#L53-L57

But how does the whole `Polymer.Base._addFeature` actually work (as in, an overview) and how does it do the whole `behaviors` side of the story?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [`_addFeature`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/273ab0fbe641209fa3fc3ce8368bb78f83db9b10/src/lib/base.html#L22) does is mix properties into `Polymer.Base`.

Polymer does some work registration-time (preprocessing, once per element type) and some work at element instance-time (when an actual element is created).

Preprocess methods only happen once and use the `_prep` or `register` prefix. For example, the [`_prepBehavior`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/273ab0fbe641209fa3fc3ce8368bb78f83db9b10/polymer.html#L53) method is called once per behavior (per class).

Instance-time methods are called once per instance and generally have `_setup` or `_marshal` prefixes. The [`_marshalBehavior`](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/273ab0fbe641209fa3fc3ce8368bb78f83db9b10/polymer.html#L104) method is called once per behavior (per instance), and this is where `listeners` are setup.

Comment: Thank you Scott! If you were to pick a spot where to place a breakpoint to start following the flow of what happens when you 1) Declare an element 2) Instance it, which ones would you pick?

Comment: 1) `Polymer()`: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/273ab0fbe641209fa3fc3ce8368bb78f83db9b10/src/lib/polymer-bootstrap.html#L22
2) `createdCallback()`: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/273ab0fbe641209fa3fc3ce8368bb78f83db9b10/src/lib/base.html#L34